# For loop inserts only 1 MySQL record

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been working on a form that allows entering a menu item for a cafe establishment, alongside its ingredients (arrays of data). Unfortunately, a problem came up as it only executes 1 query even though 2 or more ingredients were entered in the form (dynamic, jQuery).

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
include("session.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $productname = $_POST['product_name'];
    $categoryID = $_POST['categoryID'];
    $price = $_POST['srp'];

    // ingredients
    $ingredients = $_POST['ingredients'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $measure = $_POST['measure'];

    if (!empty($productname) && !empty($categoryID) && !empty($price) && !empty($ingredients) && !empty($qty) && !empty($measure)) {
        for ($i=0; $i < count($ingredients); $i++) {
            if ($ingredients[$i] != "" && $qty[$i] != "" && $measure[$i] != "") {
                mysqli_query($db, "insert into individual_ingredients values ('', '$productname', '{$ingredients[$i]}', '{$qty[$i]}', '{$measure[$i]}')");
            }
        }
        mysqli_query($db, "insert into end_products values ('', '$productname', '$price', '', '$categoryID')");
        mysqli_query($db, "insert into audit_trail values ('', now(), '{$_SESSION['login_user']}', 'New end product added')");
        header("location: end_products.php");
    } else {
        echo '<font color="red">'."Incomplete data entered".'</font>';
    }
}

?>
```

And here is the HTML form and JQuery:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $login_session; ?> | New End Product Record</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap js library -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//add more fields group
  $(".addMore").click(function(){
        var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group fieldGroup">'+$(".fieldGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';
        $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
  });
  //remove fields group
  $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){
      $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

HTML form:

```
<table style="margin: 5% -1% 0 -10%; font-size: 0.9em">
<tr>
<form action="new_end_product_record.php" method="post">
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="product_name"></td>
<td>Raw Material/s Used</td>
<td>
<div class="fieldGroup">
<select name="ingredients[]">
<option value="">Ingredient</option>

<?php
$items_sql = "select name from raw_materials where status='Active'";
$get_items = mysqli_query($db, $items_sql);

while ($option = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_items)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $option['name']; ?>"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

<input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="Quantity" style="width:60px">

<select name="measure[]">
<option value="">Measure Unit</option>
<?php
$get_units = "select * from raw_material_measures";
$units = mysqli_query($db, $get_units);
while ($unit = mysqli_fetch_assoc($units)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $unit['full_name']; ?>"><?php echo $unit['full_name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addMore">ADD</a>
<br /><br />
</div>

<!-- second set -->
<div class="fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
<div class="input-group">
<select name="ingredients[]">
<option value="">Ingredient</option>
<?php
$items_sql = "select name from raw_materials where status='Active'";
$get_items = mysqli_query($db, $items_sql);

while ($option = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_items)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $option['name']; ?>"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

<input type="text" name="qty[]" placeholder="Quantity" style="width:60px">

<select name="measure[]">
<option value="">Measure Unit</option>
<?php
$get_units = "select * from raw_material_measures";
$units = mysqli_query($db, $get_units);
while ($unit = mysqli_fetch_assoc($units)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $unit['full_name']; ?>"><?php echo $unit['full_name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove">REMOVE</a>
<br /><br />
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SRP</td>
<td><input type="text" name="srp"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Category</td>
<td>
<select name="categoryID">
<option value="">Select category...</option>
<!--list all categories in the database-->
<?php
$cat_query = "select category_ID, name from end_products_categories";
$get_cats = mysqli_query($db, $cat_query);

while ($option = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_cats)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $option['category_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $option['name']?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</td>
<!-- <td>Expiration</td>
<td><input type="date"></input></td> -->
</tr>
</table><br>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="ADD RECORD">
<input type="reset" value="ERASE ALL">
</div></form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a problem with the loop or with the HTML form that prevents the second to the last set of values from being inserted? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a side note: Your code seems to be vurnalbe to [mysql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) Please make sure your queries are secure by using 'Prepared statements' from either [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or, generally preffered, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Please add an `echo "insert into individual_ingredients values ('', '$productname', '{$ingredients[$i]}', '{$qty[$i]}', '{$measure[$i]}')"` before the line `mysqli_query($db, "insert into individual_ingredients values ('', '$productname', '{$ingredients[$i]}', '{$qty[$i]}', '{$measure[$i]}')");` to check what query is executed when, and check for [`mysqli_error`s](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after you execute the query.

Comment: Best way to check if the form is arriving correctly is by doing `var_dump($_POST);` If everything is in there, then there is something wrong with the posting of the form, if not, you should call do `mysqli_error($db)` and check what that gives you.